# Mouse driver clash with replacement mouse

Tags: usb, drivers, mouse

I hope this is the right place to ask, apologies in advance if it isn't, I'm completely new here.
I've been searching for a few hours and trying multiple things to sort it out, so far to no avail.

I have recently bought a mouse (Trust GXT900), of which unfortunately the left button stopped working a few days ago (not working on any other computer, no physical damage, no idea why). I managed to return it to the store and receive a replacement, but upon plugging it into my computer, the lights on the mouse will shortly light up and then turn off immediately, and not only will none of the movement/buttons have any effect, my pc doesn't even seem to detect the mouse at all (no message, no connect/disconnect sound).

The mouse works perfectly well on any other pc, and any other mouse works fine on mine. I noticed that on one USB port (type-C, using a conversion cable) that I had never used my previous (broken) mouse on, it *does* work, leading me to believe there is some kind of driver clash with the remains of the previous one talking to the current one, on all the other USB (type-A) ports that I have.

I've tried all that I could think of, uninstalling the main button-configuration-software, uninstalling as many mice/HID devices from device manager I could think of being relevant, reinstalling the configuration software again, but the problem persists on all the other USB ports.

Does anyone perhaps have any insights? Thank you in advance!
I'm running Windows 10 on an Asus GL504GM laptop

Comment: have you tried booting for example a USB-boot Linux on the laptop to see if the mouse is recognized there? This way you could rule out a hardware compatibility problem.

Also you might try all available USB ports on the computer, or plug it into a USB hub and then plug the hub to the laptop.

Comment: Hmm the Linux one seems interesting, although since I don't have experience with dual-booting and such I'm not sure if I could try that... Using a virtual machine would perhaps not help since windows needs to recognise the device first? My post explains it more clearly, but I did try all of my ports, and only the one I've never used the previous/broken one with, seems to function. Edit - Oh I didn't try the hub yet, I don't have one unfortunately. Thank you for the response by the way :)

Comment: You don't need to install Linux so dual booting isn't a problem, you just need to test it in the Linux environment that the "installer" has. No further than that, don't install, don't do anything with your Windows install disks, just download the Linux image, burn it to a USB stick or DVD, and then get your system to boot from it. If the mouse works then your hardware is fine.

Comment: No need to do dual booting. Ideally, you would download something like Linux Mint and copy it to a USB thumb drive, and then boot from that, without needing to install anything.

Comment: Thanks for your answers, I'll try that right away. My guess is that it's going to be fine, since the hardware of both my pc and the mouse itself seems to be functioning on their own, but I'll let you know what happens :)

Comment: Ok so I think I did everything correctly, TL;DR: the mouse did not work. I've booted the lightest mint iso from a usb stick, tried the mouse and had the same problem. Tried another mouse, worked fine. Shutdown for some reason hang on the console-like screen, which displayed messages when (un)plugging usb devices, showing when I plugged in another mouse, but showing nothing when plugging in my own mouse (the one with the problems). I'm honestly not sure where the problem could be at this point, will a Windows reinstall even have any chance of helping (last resort)?

Comment: Update: I've found a short USB extension cable (type A to type A) that I can connect the mouse to, and then plug that extension cable into one of the type A ports on my PC... and it works, mouse lights up and functions normally. I'm getting more and more confused

Comment: Sounds like you got another bad mouse, change brands.

Comment: I'm really not sure about that - it works fine on other pc's, and even without any issues using the type-C port or using something as simple as a small extension cable. I suppose I'll just try reflashing my BIOS and reinstalling windows, even though a bit drastic for a semi-nonfunctional mouse driver. I'll update once I get results